# Java delay in execution between non-blocking statements

Tags: java, jvm, real-time, delay, nonblocking

I have come upon a strange issue in one of our Java programs. Once in a while randomly some threads are delayed for up to 25 seconds in execution. This happens for 1-2 minutes and then the application is back to normal processing. It is a telephony application with strict time requirements so this is not acceptable.

Calling Class

```
    OCSIHandling ocsiHandler = new OCSIHandling(this.arg0);
    ocsiHandler.run();
```

Constructor

```
    public OCSIHandling()
    {
    //This is the last statement of the constructor after initializations
            logger.info("[" + refId + "][OCSI] SMS IDP");
    }
```

Class method

```
    run(){
    //This is the first statement of the method which is executed with delay
    logger.info("[" + refId + "][OCSI] in run()");
    }
```

**Sample log during issue**

INFO 2014-02-07 06:03:27,674 [Thread-143840672] 100 - [MGW070214060327d384][OCSI] SMS IDP
INFO 2014-02-07 06:03:49,771 [Thread-143840672] 123 - [MGW070214060327d384][OCSI] in run()

There is a delay in execution, 49-27 = 22 seconds

Program is running with -server option with a 32 bit HotSpot server VM. During this time the logging is messed up chronologically as well. 1:00:01 time stamp written before 1:00:00 and so. There is no thread pool.

We are using centos 5.4, 64-bit on a vmware client. Application is cpu intensive and there is not much memory requirement(its running with default heap size of 1GB) so I am not sure if GC can cause this much delay.

**Logback file:** http://pastebin.com/fpxYBYew

Please point me to what possible factors can lead to this kind of behaviour.

Edit: **This happens in off peak**

Comment: Try to use a profiler.  Commercial( YourKit, jprofiler,...) or VisualVm(free)

Comment: Is this possible to attach profiler to the application jvm.

Comment: is this ur custom class or the java.lang.Class?

Comment: What is going on in that new Class() constructor?  There is something that you aren't showing us as Class isn't Runnable so instance.run() can't possibly work.  That, and attach a profiler and figure out where the time goes.

Comment: This is a custom class. Constructor is initializing parameters and the last line of the constructor is a logging statement. So for the time period with issue, in the logs the last line of constructor and the first line of run() has delay.

Comment: Interesting. But you'll have to give _much_ more detail to be able to figure this out. Such as the code of the constructor in question and any methods it invokes, as well as information about the logging framework you're using and how it is configured, etc.

Comment: Try eliminating logger completely (temporarily) (it may be causing issues due to buffering, file system initialization etc.) and then use a profiler to determine the execution time of the method. And as advised above, you need to profile all other methods in your constructor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be running into a garbage collection issue? Add the following options to the `java` command when running your program (these would be included before the main class name, or before the -jar option): `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails`

This will cause detailed information about the garbage collector performance to be printed to the console (you may need to redirect output to a file). There are free programs available to analyze the output, but in your case, just looking for full garbage collections and checking the time they take might suffice.

Comment: wow I thought I cant be running into GC issues with a low memory requirement application with -server jvm parameter. Changed GC to G1 and the issue is resolved.
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400